# Using NReco.PDF Renderer.dllto create a bitmap from a PDF file fails in Win 7 unless calling program run as admin

Tags: c#, nreco

Using NReco PDF Renderer ( v 1.2.2.0) in a C# Winforms app made with Visual Studio 2019 to create a bitmap from a PDF file fails in Win 7 unless calling program run as Admin. Is there a way of using NReco.PdfRenderer.dll so that calling program in Win 7 does not need to run as Admin? This problem does not occur when running the program in Win 10.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here (which is unlikely as you haven't supplied any code), i would suggest a good-old-fashioned email to the authors. after all they want your money

Comment: They have received my money! Fortunately I found the answer by old fashioned trial and error. The Setup project of VS 2019 only seems happy to install into C:\Programs or C:\Programs (x86) - with the previous InstallShield LE used in VS 2013  for installer project I installed into C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\ProgramName, and perhaps the default permissions for users are different there. I've been using NReco.PDFRenderer for some time and had no problems until the VS2019 install.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the permissions for NReco.PdfRenderer.dll to give the Users group full control removed the problem. The installation (in C:\Programs (x86)\Program Name) only gives the dll Read and Read & execute permissions to the Users group by default. The SYSTEM and Administrators group have full control by default.